# My manager tells me i have HR meeting tomorrow

Tags: human-resources, termination, layoff

I work at one of the big 5 Canadian banks in technology. My manager told me to come with him to a private room and he tells me I have a HR meeting tomorrow Thursday (payday) at 1pm.

I ask him what it is about and he says he doesn't know. I prodded further and asked "should I be concerned about my job?" And he said my job is not at risk here.

I find it very cryptic and of course very anxious. My last 3 years of performance reviews are of a solid quality.

Also to add, our teams are severely short on staff and just hired 15+ full timers over the last 3 months. Just yesterday our AVP gave a large townhall describing the big pipeline of work coming our way, celebrated our accomplishments and reiterating why we are such a good place to work at.

Any advice? 
Do I need to prepare financially for termination?

Comment: Um...is it likely that someone who doesn't know your boss and company would have more knowledge about this than you do?  Are HR meetings often used for terminations?  Has your boss lied to you before?

Comment: I called the bank HR line and even they said they have no information on this. There were no HR terminations during my tenure. My boss has not lied before but he does tend to exaggerate stuff like "this could have been done in much lesser time etc ". Also tomorrow happens to be payday lol

Comment: Then just wait. If they wanted (or could) disclose information they would have done it.

Comment: What I find peculiar is that your boss claims he doesn't know but took you to a private room to tell you about it.

Comment: That's what I found peculiar too. He told me he doesn't know the purpose of the meeting. That said, I'm aware of the HR meeting at 1pm tomorrow but no meeting room was booked. On our floor meeting rooms are extremely hard to book...

Comment: If he does not know what the meeting is about then how would he know your job is not at risk?   What can you do but go the meeting?

Comment: Make sure to come and let us know tomorrow what's up

Comment: Also if you were being terminated it would have been done when your boss pulled you into the office. When I was a manager I had everything done for the termination short of sending out the notification email done. Walk you to the room, tell you your employment is terminated effective immediately, and give you a box of your stuff. There would be no "oh you have a meeting tomorrow with HR" if you were being termed. You could mess too much up with prior warning

Comment: +1 @BirdLawExpert  In my experience, if HR and/or your boss are planning to terminate you, they won't give you advanced notice of the meeting.

Comment: It is not clear what you want us to help you with, besides we cannot possibly help you any more than making random guesses. Your boss already told you your job is not at risk, but it appears that you don't want to believe it, which makes me wonder why you bothered asking him in the first place. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: A lot of non-concerning stuff: technical/administrative contract changes, some questionnaire about workplace conditions

Comment: I guess you'll have your answer in about 6 hours.

Comment: @ZachA, well, what happened?

Answer (score 10):

It could be literally anything.

- Your boss could be lying and you're getting fired. Unlikely because firings usually happen immediately so you don't have time to prepare.
- You could be being laid off in the near or mid future, or given the opportunity to take severance and leave voluntarily or risk layoffs in the future.  That's pretty common
- You could be getting discipline for something. Perhaps you said something you shouldn't have or someone made a complaint about you.
- You could be getting a promotion (or be offered one).  You never know.
- You could be being transferred to a different department or location

If I were to make a wild, random guess, I would speculate it's either a transfer of some sort or:

- Someone **else** is being investigated and you're going to be asked if you saw anything or know anything about it. This sort of thing is very common when a company is being sued.

Comment: I sincerely hope it's not the first point. I was terminated in my previous job of 3 years without advance notice and around 1-2pm. It could be a possible transfer because I was shuffled around 3 teams that needed help as my boss claimed

Comment: @ZachA Your first point explains your worries. Your second would explain why your boss wouldn't know the topic of the meeting (he might like to keep you on his team). For your peace of mind (and because, as Kilisi said, there is anyhow not much you can do) I would go with your second idea for now.

Answer (score 5):

> Do I need to prepare financially for termination?

Not a lot you can prepare in half a day. Relax and see what eventuates. Unless you're getting fired which you have been told is not happening then there is nothing positive in getting upset about it.

Wait until you have more information then move forwards from that.